# code conflict daneWilliams/jquery.dropdown with my codes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to use https://github.com/daneWilliams/jquery.dropdown which helps me to create advanced menu but the problem is that I have to call that like this:

```
<script>
$(function() {

    $('select, ul').dropdown();

});
</script>
```

Which make big problem in my site .It would change all of my select and ul elements of my website and It make a mess.

How should I call that without having infliction with my codes?

Thanks

Comment: Could you give us some demo or link to your Website?

Comment: Although i am not familiar with this plugin, I think you can use a normal jquery selector to achieve what you want, for example `$('.change').dropdown();`